# Removing Tags using sed

Tags: html, shell, command

i want remove the tags of following line using sed command in a single command line and i want output to be:- Release Date:September 10,2013

```
<p><strong>Release date:</strong> September 10, 2013</p>
```

Comment: `.. using sed command in a single command line and i want output to be ..`.  ok, what did you try?

Comment: [Cannot parse html with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `sed` command should remove tags:

```
sed 's/<[^>]\+>//g' file
```

Comment: Thank you, I was using sed twice to remove tags                                1) to remove <p>and</p> 2)to remove <strong> and </strong> using e,because i couldn't able to compare more than two pattern at a time:-  1)    sed -e 's/<strong>/ /' -e 's/<\/strong>/ /g' grepfile                  2)sed -e 's/<p>/ /g' -e 's/<\/p>/ /g' grepfile

Comment: It's a regex that matches strings of the form `<...>` and `sed` replaces them with nothing. Take a look at a regex tutorial if you cannot understand regexes.

Answer (score 0):

The following awk command

```
awk 'gsub(/ *<[^>]*> */," ")'
```

Comment: gsub replaces all of the longest, leftmost, nonoverlapping matching substrings it can find.The gsub function returns the number of substitutions made. If the variable to be searched and altered, target, is omitted, then the entire input record, $0, is used

Comment: it checks for the regular expression and replaces with space,space doesn't effect the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below

```
echo "<p><strong>Release date:</strong> September 10, 2013</p>" | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g'
```